# Vuejs, al cambiar de pagina de los resultados obtenidos no se actualizan ciertas variables

Tags: vue.js

tengo dos componentes, uno llamado : **buscador** y otro **fichero-miniatura**,
el **buscador** se encarga de de filtrar ficheros de forma asincrona segun lo que escriba en el buscador y cargarlos en su componente hijo **fichero-miniatura**.

Este buscador carga los resultados de forma dividida divididos por una paginación, es decir, si la busqueda da como resultado 10 ficheros, carga una paginación que muestra 3 de esos ficheros por pagina.
Cada **fichero-miniatura** tiene dos botones también, uno de borrado y otro de edición de nombre,  el boton de cambiar nombre lo que hace es esconder el label y poner un input con dicho nombre para que el usuario ponga el nuevo nombre que desee, y abajo del input nuevo apareceran dos botones: ok (sy quieres confirmar el nuevo nombre) y Cancelar. Al guardar se queda el nuevo nombre sin problemas. Hasta aqui bien.

Recuerdan que dije que los resultados se dividian por paginación ? **pues el  problema comienza cuando pulso el boton de ir a otra pagina (ya sea boton de siguiente pagina o boton de ir a una pagina en concreto)** . Al hacer eso,cuando quiera renombrar los ficheros que estaban en las otras paginas cargados con la misma busqueda me sale en la casilla de edición los nombre de los 3 ficheros de la primera pagina.

Por tanto si busco : 'persona' y obtengp **6 resultados** (3 por página):

```
  persona-1 persona-2 persona-3               persona-4 persona-5 persona-6
 
  (pag-1)                                     (pag-2)
```

Entonces si edito la `persona-4` me saldra en el input la `persona-1`, al editar la `persona-5` me saldrá la `persona-2`,etc...

**Pero cuando le doy a borrar y me sale la confirmacion de OK (borrar) o Cancelar, y entonces, ahora si, le doy a editar si sale bien el nombre**. ¿Será por algo que hace el boton eliminar? **Mi sugerencia para arreglar esto la pondre abajo del todo para pediros apoyo para hacerlo**

Componente Vue **buscador**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group" style="position:relative;">
                        <gif-loading style="position:absolute; right:0;bottom:3px;right:3px; " :show="labelButtonAdvancedSearching === 'Buscando ..' ? true : false"></gif-loading>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" @keyup="buscar" placeholder="Nombre del archivo que deseas bucar.." v-model="fileNameToFind">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right my-2">
                        <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary">Hola</button> -->
                        <button class="btn" :class="[labelButtonAdvancedSearching === 'Buscando ..' ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-secondary']" @click="busqAv = !busqAv">{{labelButtonAdvancedSearching}}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" rounded bg-primary p-3 sombra"  v-if="busqAv"  style="position:absolute;z-index:3;width:100%;">
                        <div class="form-group border bg-secondary text-light p-3" id="orden">
                            <h5>Orden.</h5>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="orden_created_at_desc" name="order_created_at" checked>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="orden_created_at_desc">Por creación (de mas nuevo a mas antiguo)</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="order_create_at_asc" name="order_created_at">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="order_create_at_asc">Por creacion (de mas antiguo a mas nuevo)</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="order_word_desc" name="order_word" checked>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="order_word_desc">Alfabeticamente (A-Z)</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="order_word_asc" name="order_word">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="order_word_asc">Alfabeticamente (Z-A)</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Extension</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group border bg-secondary text-light p-3" id="tipo_archivo">
                            <h5>Tipo de archivo.</h5>
                            <hr>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="all_tipo" name="filtro_tipo" checked>
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="all_tipo">Todos.</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="documento" name="filtro_tipo">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="documento">Documentos</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="imagen" name="filtro_tipo">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="imagen">Imagenes</label>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group border bg-secondary text-light p-3" id="tipo_extension">
                            <h5>Tipo de extensión.</h5>
                            <hr>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="all" name="filtro_extension">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="all">Todas.</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="png" name="filtro_extension">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="png">png</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="jpg" name="filtro_extension">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="jpg">jpg</label>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="advanced_searching_result">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12  my-2" v-for="(file,index) in foundFiles['data']" :key="file+index">
                    <fichero-miniatura  :fichero_param="file" :root_dir="root_dir" ></fichero-miniatura>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pagination -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                     <nav>
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item" v-show="foundFiles['prev_page_url']">
                                <a href="#" class="page-link" @click.prevent="getPreviousPage">
                                    <span>
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item text-white" :class="{ 'active': (foundFiles['current_page']=== n) }" :key="n" v-for="n in foundFiles['last_page']">
                                <a href="#" class="page-link" @click.prevent="getPage(n)">
                                    <span >
                                        {{ n }}
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item" v-show="foundFiles['next_page_url']">
                                <a href="#" class="page-link" @click.prevent="getNextPage">
                                    <span>
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['root_dir'],
        data(){
            return{
                fileNameToFind:'',
                busqAv:false,
                foundFiles:[],
                labelButtonAdvancedSearching:'Busqueda Avanzada',
                currentPage:1
            }
        },
        methods:{
            buscar(){
                console.log('Page : '+this.currentPage);
                this.labelButtonAdvancedSearching = 'Buscando ..';
                let that = this;
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('file_name_to_find',this.fileNameToFind);

                 axios.post('/file/advanced_searching?page='+this.currentPage,data).then(
                    (response) => {
                        let data = response.data;
                        that.foundFiles = data.result;
                        that.labelButtonAdvancedSearching = 'Busqueda Avanzada';
                        console.log(that.foundFiles);
                    },
                    error=>{
                        console.log('Error al actualizar el nombre de la imagen');
                        that.labelButtonAdvancedSearching = 'Busqueda Avanzada';
                    }
                )
            },
            getPage(page){
                this.currentPage = page;
                this.buscar();

            },
            getPreviousPage(){
                this.currentPage--;
                this.buscar();
            },
            getNextPage(){
                this.currentPage++;
                this.buscar();
            },
        },

    }
</script>
```

Componente Vue **fichero-miniatura**:

```
<template>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"  title="">
        <a id="imagen" :href="'/fichero/'+fichero_param.id" target="_blank">
            <iconizador  :fichero_param="fichero_param" :root_dir="root_dir" ></iconizador>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6  v-if="!editableName" class="card-title" style="overflow-x: scroll; height:50px;">{{fichero_param.nombre_real}}</h6>
            <input  v-if="editableName" class="form-control-sm" v-model="newName" >

            <!-- Renombrar - Borrar -->
            <div id="botonera" v-if="!editableName && !deletableFile">
                <button @click="editableName = true" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Renombrar</button>
                <button @click="deletableFile = true" class="btn btn-sm  btn-danger">Borrar</button>
            </div>

            <!-- OK - Cancelar -->
            <div v-else class="mt-3">
                <button @click="newName=fichero_param.nombre_real;renameOrDelete" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">OK</button>
                <button @click="editableName = false; deletableFile = false; newName=fichero_param.nombre_real" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    #imagen :hover{
        box-shadow:'30px 1px 5px blue';
        width:'80%';
        transition:0.5s;
        border-bottom-right-radius:30%;
        border: red  10px;

    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        props:
        {
            'fichero_param':{
                type:Object,
                default:{
                    nombre_real:'error'
                }
            },
            'root_dir':{
                type:String,
                default:''
            }
        },
        data(){
            return{
                fichero:{},
                editableName:false,
                deletableFile:false,
                newName:''
            }
        },
        methods:{
            renameOrDelete(){
                if (this.editableName) {
                    this.rename();
                } else {
                    this.delete();
                }
            },
            rename(){
                // console.log(this.fichero);
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('file',this.fichero);
                data.append('new_name',this.newName);
                data.append('_method','patch');

                console.log('new name = '+this.newName);
                let that = this;
                axios.post('/fichero/'+this.fichero.id, data).then(
                    response => {
                        console.log('response.data');
                        console.log(response.data);
                        let data = response.data;

                        if (data.result === true) {
                            // that.fichero = data.file
                            console.log('that.newName = '+that.newName);
                            that.fichero.nombre_real = that.newName;
                            that.editableName = false;
                        }
                    },
                    error=>{
                        console.log('Error al actualizar el nombre de la imagen');
                    }
                )
            },
            delete(){
                console.log('delete !');
                axios.delete('/fichero/'+this.fichero.id).then(
                    response => {
                        console.log('response.data');
                        console.log(response.data);
                        let data = response.data;

                    },
                    error=>{
                        console.log('Error al actualizar el nombre de la imagen');
                    }
                )
            }
        },
         beforeMount() {
                this.fichero = this.$props.fichero_param;
                this.newName = this.fichero.nombre_real;
            }
    }
</script>
```

---

Como decia al principio el **boton eliminar hace algo que lo arregla**:

```
        <button @click="editableName = false; deletableFile = false; newName=fichero_param.nombre_real" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
```

En concreto es esto: `newName=fichero_param.nombre_real` entonces creo que puede ser que al cambiar de pagina se quede desactualizada esa var, **¿Podria hacer como un evento de padre a hijo para que recargara eso?** Se que para pasar info de padre a hijo es por props pero no hay algun evento que se desencadeene al  clickar en una pagina y actualizar eso ??

Un saludo.